# Override local extension that overrides core

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, overrides

```
<global>
  <models>
    <sales>
      <rewrite>
      <order_pdf_invoice>Local_Extension_Model_Sales_Order_Pdf_Invoice</order_pdf_invoice>
      </rewrite>
    </sales>
  </models>
</global>
```

**This is in the local extension that Im trying to override.**

So in my `/etc/extension.xml` file I put that it depends on **Local_Extension**, I also put it in my `etc/config.xml` file I then used the exact same rewrite as they did in their `config.xml` but using my path and when I look at the Modules conflict detector it says that my class overrode the class, but it is not being used.

In that same Modules Conflict Detector it shows the initial class being

`Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice`

and the rewrites are

```
MyCompany_InvoicePdf_Model_Sales_Order_Pdf_Invoice
Local_Extension_Model_Sales_Order_Pdf_Invoice
```

the **Local_Extension** is green which means it's being used and **MyCompany** is red saying "Red class name means that probably there is conflict. Initial class has been overwritten by this class, but this class is not used.

You should check if this class doesn't contain any important methods or changes, which should be used."

In my class file `Invoice.php` the first line is:

> class MyCompany_InvoicePdf_Model_Sales_Order_Pdf_Invoice extends
>
> Local_Extension_Model_Sales_Order_Pdf_Invoice

But I must be missing something...? Any help!? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`app/code/local/Thenew/Module/etc/config.xml`

```
...
<global>
  <models>
    <local_localmodule>//the first one
      <rewrite>
          <model>Thenew_Module_Model_Sales_Order_Pdf_Invoice</model>//the new one
      </rewrite>
    </local_localmodule>
  </models>
</global>
...
```

`app/etc/modules/Thenew_Module.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Thenew_Module> //the new one
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <local_localmodule/>//the local one that you want to rewrite
            </depends>
        </Thenew_Module>
    </modules>
</config>
```

So here Magento loads first `Local_Localmodule` then `Thenew_Module`